# Magento - cannot access to action in controller just create

Tags: php, magento

When I try to access url `http://localhost/magento/index.php/happyhour/hello/helloWorld`, I get an error "404 Not Found 1". Here are some files:
Foggyline_HappyHour.xml in app\etc\modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foggyline_HappyHour>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Foggyline_HappyHour>
    </modules>
</config>
```

config.xml in app\code\community\Fogglyline\HappyHour\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <FoggylineHappyHour>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </FoggylineHappyHour>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <foggyline_happyhour>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
                    <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
                </args>
            </foggyline_happyhour>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And final file HelloController in app\code\community\Fogglyline\HappyHour\controllers

```
<?php
    class Foggyline_HappyHour_HelloController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
    {
        public function helloWorldAction()
        {
            echo 'Hello World #1.';
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is full code file I wrote: http://www.mediafire.com/download/6r13ljv32gp8m6i/Foggyline.rar. Please show me what I wrong! This is the first time I've written extension so I don't know where errors is. Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app\code\community\Fogglyline\HappyHour\etc` change this to `app\code\community\Foggyline\HappyHour\etc` and also the folder name..tested on my local it works..

Comment: take care of your naming conventions and try to use easier package and module names

Answer (score 1):

change this code to following code and check

```
<modules>
        <Foggyline_HappyHour>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Foggyline_HappyHour>
    </modules>
```

Let me know if it is worked for you.

or you refere to the below link for debuging

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189935/magento-extension-404-error
```

Comment: I changed but nothing happened :(

Comment: might not make a difference.. but anytime I make any changes like this I always empty the Magento caches.. Magento caching can be a pain a lot of the time